# Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy with Hasura Postgres BaaS?

Tags: hasura

I am trying to find out if it's possible to use SQLAlchemy with [Hasura](http://hasura.io/). If yes, what would be the database URL?

Comment: Can you provide an example of code? If it is not related to coding/programming, maybe you have to post this in a different channel than stackoverflow.

Comment: @ashwani You should check the docs out and let us know if you're facing a specific code problem. https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/custom-microservices/connecting-to-postgres-from-microservice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

These are your database variables:

1. DB endpoint: postgres.hasura
2. Username: admin
3. Password: `hasura secrets ls | grep postgres.password`

You can hard-code 1, 2 in your source code, but I would recommend you get the password using a kubernetes `secretKeyRef` in your `k8s.yaml`.

> Detailed docs here:
>   https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/custom-microservices/connecting-to-postgres-from-microservice.html